# SceneKit - Movement + Gravity = Strange Movement

Tags: swift, scenekit

My Scene:

- One ball (Dynamic Physics Body)
- One cube as platform (Static Physics Body)
- Default Scene-Gravity
- Default masses

When I run the scene the ball falls correctly on the platform.
But when I add movement (delta-time movement on the x-axis in the render method), the ball falls strange/slowly down.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49212390/edit) your question to make it on-topic as explained in the help page: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic physics bodies should only be moved using physics, e.g.`applyForce(_:at:asImpulse:)` You may be able to get it to work by calling `resetTransform()` after updating the position, but at a cost to performance.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsbody/1514782-resettransform